# CSV module looks for file not mentioned in code (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

For some reason I encounter an error in all files where the CSV-module is imported. The error refers to a file (naam_bestand.csv) that is not mentioned in the code.

This is the error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxx/Python/mac/webscraping_2.py", line 3, in <module> import csv
  File "/xxx/Python/mac/csv.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open("naam_bestand.csv", "r") as csv_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'naam_bestand.csv'
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/michelhofman/Dropbox/Python/mac/webscraping_2.py']]
[dir: /Users/michelhofman/Dropbox/Python/mac]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

source = requests.get("https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics+card").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

with open("newegg_prijzen2.csv", "w") as new_file:
    fieldnames = ["brand", "product", "price"]

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    items = soup.find_all("div", class_="item-container")

    for item in items:
        brand = item.find("a", class_="item-brand").img["title"]
        product = item.find("a", class_="item-title").text
        price = item.find("li", class_="price-current").strong.text
        csv_writer.writerow(brand, product, price)
```

This happens to other files where I import the csv module too.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a file called `csv.py`. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution... When playing around with the CSV module, I had saved this test file called csv.py in the same folder as the above mentioned document.